# Remove observer for NotificationCenter - "Variable used within its own initial value"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notificationcenter

I do not understand how to remove an observer for a notification using a block.

```
var block = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .notifName, object: obj, queue: OperationQueue.current, using: { notification in
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(block)

            // Do stuff
        })
```

This presents a compiler error "Variable used within its own initial value". How can I remove this observer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler complains because it does not "know" that the closure
is executed only *after* the observer has been created and assigned
to the variable.

You can declare the observer variable as an *implicitly unwrapped optional* because it is guaranteed to have a value when the block
is executed:

```
var observer: NSObjectProtocol!
observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: ..., object: ..., queue: ...,
                                                  using: { notification in

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)

    // Do stuff
})
```

Comment: Great! The apple documentation show an example of this working in Objective-C that is a little tricky to make work for Swift.